# Hide network drives with AppleScript

Tags: networking, applescript, drive

is there a way to do so in as?

Background:

I don't want to show network drives which are not used from a user.

I know how to mount drives

`tell application "Finder" try set userName to do shell script "whoami" mount volume "smb://..." end try end tell`

But I don't have any idea what to do to hide unused network drives.

Comment: Hide them in what way? Do you mean the icon on the desktop? Please elaborate.

Comment: Hey, yeah that's I meant. Simply hide so that It's not visible in the network section in Finder anymore.